Perché tutte queste cancellazioni?
Noto che @Gae.S. ha cancellato varie sue risposte. Se mi leggi: perché? Liberissimo/a, ovviamente, ma se c'è qualcosa che non va con questo sito, forse sarebbe più utile anche per altri farlo notare qui nel Meta, o parlarne con i moderatori.
